# How do I specify a specific enum value as a hidden field using Simple Form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I have a `PortStock.rb` model, that has the following enum:

```
class PortStock < ApplicationRecord    
  enum action: [ :buy, :sell ]
end
```

What I want to do is on my form partial, I want to include either `PortStock.buy` or `PortStock.sell` as a hidden field (this will be determined by the params sent with the form).

I don't know what to put in the `value:` attribute of my `input_field` below.

```
<%= f.input_field :action, as: :hidden, value: ??? %>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) says the following:

> ...
>
> Finally, it's also possible to explicitly map the relation between attribute and database integer with a hash:
>
> ```
> class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
>   enum status: { active: 0, archived: 1 }
> end
> ```
>
> Note that when an array is used, the implicit mapping from the values to database integers is derived from the order the values appear in the array. In the example, `:active` is mapped to `0` as it's the first element, and `:archived` is mapped to `1`. In general, the `i`-th element is mapped to `i-1` in the database.
>
> Therefore, once a value is added to the enum array, its position in the array must be maintained, and new values should only be added to the end of the array. To remove unused values, the explicit hash syntax should be used.
>
> In rare circumstances you might need to access the mapping directly. The mappings are exposed through a class method with the pluralized attribute name, which return the mapping in a `HashWithIndifferentAccess`:
>
> ```
> Conversation.statuses[:active]    # => 0
> Conversation.statuses["archived"] # => 1
> ```
>
> ...

This means you can solve your problem in 1 of 2 ways.

1. ```
   <%= f.input_field :action, as: :hidden, value: 0 %>
   ```
2. ```
   <%= f.input_field :action, as: :hidden, value: PortStock.actions[:buy] %>
   ```

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation. This works perfectly (specifically the second one).